# MVC3 Remote Validation not generating data-val-remote

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Scripts (included in below order):

```
/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js
/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js
/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
```

Model:

public class Users
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Guid UserID { get; set; }

```
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Username required.")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Min: 5, Max: 30 characters")]
    [Remote("IsUsername_Available", "Users", AdditionalFields = "Email", HttpMethod="Post", ErrorMessage = "Username already exists.")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password required.")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "Min: 5, Max: 30 characters")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

}

View:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create",null,new AjaxOptions(){ UpdateTargetId="form1" }, new { id = "form1", @class = "small-forms" }))
{    
    <fieldset>
        <legend>User Registration</legend>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col1">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Users.Username)</div>
            <div class="col2">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Users.Username, new { @class = "textbox" })</div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Users.Username)
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col1">@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Users.Password)</div>
            <div class="col2">@Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Users.Password, new { @class = "textbox" })</div>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Users.Password)
        </div>
</fieldset>
}
```

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult IsUsername_Available(string Username, string Email)
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Generated HTML Input tag for username:

```
<input name="Users.Username" class="text-box single-line" id="Users_Username" type="text" data-val-required="Username required." data-val-length-min="5" data-val-length-max="30" data-val-length="Min: 5, Max: 30 characters" data-val="true" value=""/>
```

Its strange not finding remote validation attribute. I'm really struggling to solve this. I don't know where the things going wrong. Please help me.

Comment: I'm not answering this question directly while Something looks a little confusing! why your HttpMethod atttribute is Post while the controller action is not HttpPost? Is this a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: Ok. sorry, Neither the HttpMethod nor the controller action is POST.

Comment: Okay! I have tried your code and it doesn't work as It is. But when I remove your additional parameters (with this : [Remote("IsUsername_Available", "Users")]), It works.

Comment: No ADA... it doesn't work for me... tried the same code.